# How to expose host network to docker container in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Well, the question is simple; how do I pass `--net=host` when executing `docker-compose`?

```
eclipse:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: eclipse-dockerfile
    image: eclipse-docker:latest
    volumes:
        - "$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw"
    networks:
        - "host"
    environment:
        - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
```

Apparently does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `network_mode: "host"`

At the time on this post *the host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.*

---

Here is a quick demo:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-svc-in-host-net:
    image: nginx
    network_mode: "host"
```

Compose up:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Access nginx on localhost(the nginx image listens by default on port 80 - therefore no need to specify the port in the curl example):

```
curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
[...]
</body>
</html>
```